# How are the NEO LEAP-1A engines attached on the A320?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, engine, airbus-a320, airbus

How many bolts hold the NEO LEAP-1A engine to the pylon at the forward mount and at the aft mount?

Answer (score 4):

[This page](http://lcq8110.net/Engine2.htm) shows a schematic of the mounts for the original A320.  There are 4 bolts and 2 shear pins at the front mount, and another 4 bolts and 2 shear pins at the aft mount. In general terms, the A320neo pylon and mount system design was kept very similar to the original A320 design.  So it's a good guess that the number of bolts is the same, although I was not able to find any source to confirm that.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Much appreciate your efforts to find the answer.

Comment: ...though it looks like the diagrams are for the older V2500 engines.